# How to clone a Vuex array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vuex array (`this.buildings`). I can't mutate it directly before turning it into a payload for an api, so I tried to clone it with `slice()`:

```
const buildingsPayload = this.buildings.slice() 
  buildingsPayload.forEach((building, index) => {
  building.index = index
})
```

However I'm still getting the `Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.` error.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const buildingsPayload = this.buildings.map((b, idx) => Object.assign({ index: idx }, b));
```

It will also copy the objects, so you're not modifying the state of those.